# Trying to add relations in Backendless. No error but total count of relations added is always 0

Tags: android, backendless

Hi guys I am trying to save objects with relations in Backendless via API. I have two classes namely Task and Reminder. A task can be associated with many reminders hence I want a 1:N relationship between the Task table and Reminder table in Backendless. My Task class is as follows:

```
public class Task {


    public Date created;
    public Date updated;
    private List<Reminder> reminders = null;
    private String ownerId;
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private String objectId;
    @NonNull
    private String taskTitle;
    @NonNull
    private Date deadline;
    @NonNull
    private int isCompleted = 0;
    @NonNull
    private int isExpired = 0;


    public String getOwnerId() {
        return ownerId;
    }

    public void setOwnerId(String ownerId) {
        this.ownerId = ownerId;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId(@NonNull String objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    public List<Reminder> getReminders() {
        return reminders;
    }

    public void setReminders(List<Reminder> reminders) {
        this.reminders = reminders;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public Date getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }

    public void setUpdated(Date updated) {
        this.updated = updated;
    }

    @NonNull
    public int getIsCompleted() {
        return isCompleted;
    }

    public void setIsCompleted(@NonNull int isCompleted) {
        this.isCompleted = isCompleted;
    }

    @NonNull
    public int getIsExpired() {
        return isExpired;
    }

    public void setIsExpired(@NonNull int isExpired) {
        this.isExpired = isExpired;
    }

    public String getTaskTitle() {
        return taskTitle;
    }

    public void setTaskTitle(String taskTitle) {
        this.taskTitle = taskTitle;
    }

    public Date getDeadline() {
        return deadline;
    }

    public void setDeadline(Date deadline) {
        this.deadline = deadline;
    }


}
```

Reminder Class:

```
public class Reminder {

    private String title;
    private Date time;
    private String objectId;




    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Date getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(Date time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId(String objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }
}
```

I am saving the objects and setting up the relation as below:

```
    public void saveTaskToServer(final Task task) {
        List<Reminder> remindersList = new ArrayList<>();

   remindersList = task.getReminders();
final List<Reminder> savedReminders = new ArrayList<>();

        if(remindersList!=null && remindersList.size()!=0) {
            for
                    (Reminder reminder : remindersList) {

                reminder.setTitle(task.getTaskTitle());

                Backendless.Persistence.save(reminder, new AsyncCallback<Reminder>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleResponse(Reminder response) {
                        savedReminders.add(response);

                                  }

                    @Override
                    public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {

                        Log.i("error saving remidners", fault.toString());
                    }
                });


            }
        }
 Backendless.Persistence.save(task, new AsyncCallback<Task>() {
                @Override
                public void handleResponse(Task response) {

                    newTask = response;
                    Log.i("id is ", newTask.getObjectId());

                    insertTask(response);
                    snackbarMessage.postValue("Task Created Successfully.");

                }

                @Override
                public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {

                    Log.i("error", fault.getMessage());
                }
            });





        Backendless.Persistence.of(Task.class).addRelation(task, "reminders", savedReminders, new AsyncCallback<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public void handleResponse(Integer response) {
                Log.i("response", "added" + response);
                newTask.setReminders(savedReminders);
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                Log.i("response", "error" + fault.toString());
            }
        });

    }
```

I have tried saving the relation using the tablename:Class:n instead of the parentColumnName. Also tried saving the objectids of the reminders instead of the reminder objects themselves.The task and reminder objects get saved properly in the backendless console in their respective tables but the reminder column in the Task table still remains empty and no relations get added. Relations count in the backendless call in Android Studio also returns 0. Any advice is really appreciated. I have been following [this](https://backendless.com/feature-1-saving-objects-with-relations/) example.

Answer (score 1):

My relations were not getting saved because I was using the async callbacks in backendless!! I dont know why I didnt see that before. Since the save calls were being made before the async callbacks could finish I was ending up with null values. Fixed it by making the calls synchronous and wrapping them in an async task.